How can I log Q-values of DQN using custom callback from stable baselines 3 in Tensorboard?
I am trying to log Q-values using custom callback, but I am new in this field and not sure the code below is the correct way to do it.
class CustomLoggingCallback(BaseCallback):
    def __init__(self, verbose=1):
        super(CustomLoggingCallback, self).__init__(verbose)

    def _on_step(self) -> bool:
        # Log Q-values
        obs = th.tensor(self.locals["replay_buffer"].observations[-1], device=self.model.device).float()
        q_values = self.model.q_net(obs)
        avg_q_values = q_values.mean().item()
        self.logger.record('q_values/mean', avg_q_values)

        return True

Once I use custom callback, it reduces the performance as well. If anyone tell me how to log Q-values during the training process of DQN using stable-baselines3, I'd appreciate it.
